# Xamarin tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to develop TensorFlow on an android device, So far I trained with python and export model to Protobuf `.pb` file

the `.pb` file tested on python and its return no error

```
    ......
graph = load_graph("./frozen_model.pb")
    for op in graph.get_operations():
        print(op.name)

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        tf_predik = graph.get_tensor_by_name("prefix/tf_pred:0")
        tf_data = graph.get_tensor_by_name("prefix/tf_data:0")
        img = np.invert(Image.open("7.png").convert('L')).ravel(); image = array(img).reshape(1, 28,28,1);
        fd = {tf_data: image};
        test_pred = sess.run(tf_predik, feed_dict=fd); temp = np.argmax(test_pred, axis=1); print(temp)
```

My try on In Xamarin Android:

```
using Org.Tensorflow.Contrib.Android;
.....

var assets = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;
                var inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(assets, "frozen_model.pb");
     using (Stream inputSteam = this.Assets.Open("7.png"))
                {

                    byte[] bytes = inputSteam.ReadAllBytes();// convert to byte array???


                    inferenceInterface.Feed("tf_data", bytes, bytes.Length);
                    inferenceInterface.Run(new [] { "tf_pred:0" });
                    inferenceInterface.Fetch("tf_pred:0", predictions);
                    ....

                }
```

I get an error:

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expects arg[0] to be float but uint8 is provided

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Expects arg[0] to be float but uint8 is provided

`TensorFlowInferenceInterface.Feed` is expecting an array of float and thus you need to convert that asset-based image, decode its file encoding (jpg|png|...) to a Bitmap and obtain the float array from that.

#### Android Bitmap To Float Array

```
public float[] AndroidBitmapToFloatArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    // Assuming a square image to sample|process, adjust based upon your model requirements
    const int sizeX = 255;
    const int sizeY = 255;

    float[] floatArray;
    int[] intArray;
    using (var sampleImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, sizeX, sizeY, false).Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, false))
    {
        floatArray = new float[sizeX * sizeY * 3];
        intArray = new int[sizeX * sizeY];
        sampleImage.GetPixels(intArray, 0, sizeX, 0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);
        sampleImage.Recycle();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; ++i)
    {
        var intValue = intArray[i];
        floatArray[i * 3 + 0] = ((intValue & 0xFF) - 104);
        floatArray[i * 3 + 1] = (((intValue >> 8) & 0xFF) - 117);
        floatArray[i * 3 + 2] = (((intValue >> 16) & 0xFF) - 123);
    }
    return floatArray;
}
```

#### Example:

```
float[] feedArray;
using (var imageAsset = Assets.Open("someimage"))
using (var bitmappAsset = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(imageAsset))
{
    feedArray = AndroidBitmapToFloatArray(bitmappAsset);
}
inferenceInterface.Feed("tf_data", feedArray, feedArray.Length);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for your Solution @sushihangover, I train with 1 chanel image , how to convert to 1 chanel float array?

Comment: @AzisDodol Are your PNGs 8-bit grayscale or 8-bit RGB?

Comment: its  grayscale , i try to use opencv  it seem promising : Imgproc.Filter2D(mat, mat, CvType.Cv32fc1, mat); mat.Get(0, 0, new float[784]);

Comment: its no error return, but the output is zero, its something wrong somewhere?

Comment: Finally I found the problem, I forget to invert the image! Thank you @sushihangover

Comment: @AzisDodol So did you end up just using OpenCV to convert the bitmap to a mat?

Comment: yes I convert image to mat, and then to grayscale->invert image->convert to float array, and then feed to tensorflow model

Comment: @AzisDodol Nice, did not know you were already using OpenCV... you should add your code as a new answer for others to see. 

Comment: sure,Thanks! i will post as new answer